# tabs problem in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have created 8 tabs in a tabbed panel using Java Swing. The problem is when I enter data in any tab and click the save button. After clicking it leaves the present tab/panel and goes to the first tab.

I have to retain on the same tab after clicking the save button.

Please help me on this.

Comment: It might help if you include the relevant portion of code

Comment: At least you need to show us the code executed (ActionListener) when the save button is clicked, otherwise nobody can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, just forgot to comment the `getFrame().dispose()` method.

Thanks for your concern.